# Does npm build include unnecessary functionalities of a package as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose, I chose to use an Icon from React-Icon library.

```
import {HomeIcon} from 'react-icons'
```

Since the library have tons of icons and I only used one of them. During NPM BUILD does node.js also include whole load of icons available in the library or just the icons that I have imported.

Same goes for other libraries. Does the final npm build include only functions that I have imported or does it include whole library in final build?.

Comment: `npm build` does whatever the entry in `package.json#scripts` tells it to. Whether that does any tree shaking or other optimisation depends on what exactly it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a standard `webpack` based configuration, this depends on your imports. It will include everything into your bundle which is part of the dependency tree of you entry point. If you `import * as _ from "lodash"` it will include the whole library for example, while `import has from "lodash/has"` will only include that function.

To reduce bundle size further, you can apply tree shaking, code splitting, minification etc. Check out the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)